# VBA Vlookup for Adresses with removing duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking at a problem where I have following Excel set up:

```
1 Mainstreet 1
1 Mainstreet 2
1 Yorkstreet 1
1 Yorkstreet 2
```

Where in column A is the 1 and in B the street including the number.

Now I want to have a Vlookup, which searches for the 1 and gives out:

Mainstreet 1, 2, Yorkstreet 1, 2

I have already set up an code with the help of searching through blogs (see end of the question), however it gives out.

Mainstreet 1,2, Yorkstreet 2,

I think that the problem lies within the "removedupes2" formula, which also identifies the 2 from Yorkstreet as text and consequentyl removes it.

Does anyone have a clue? :)

Thank you in advance :)

Find my code below:

```
    Function StrSort(ByVal sInp As String, _
    Optional bDescending As Boolean = False) As String
     ' sorts a comma-delimited string
    Dim asSS()  As String ' substring array
    Dim sSS     As String ' temp string for exchange
    Dim n       As Long
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim j       As Long

    asSS = Split(sInp, ",")
    n = UBound(asSS)

    For i = 0 To n
        asSS(i) = Trim(asSS(i))
    Next

    If n <= 1 Then
        StrSort = sInp
    Else
        For i = 0 To n - 1
            For j = i + 1 To n
                If (asSS(j) < asSS(i)) Xor bDescending Then
                    sSS = asSS(i)
                    asSS(i) = asSS(j)
                    asSS(j) = sSS
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        StrSort = Join(asSS, ", ")
    End If
End Function

Function RemoveDupes2(txt As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String
    Dim x

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each x In Split(txt, delim)
            If Trim(x) <> "" And Not .exists(Trim(x)) Then .Add Trim(x), Nothing
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then RemoveDupes2 = Join(.keys, delim)
    End With
End Function

Function Myvlookup(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)

Dim r As Range
Dim result As String
Dim result2 As String
Dim result3 As String
result = ""
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        result = result & ", " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next r

result2 = Right(result, Len(result) - 2)

result3 = StrSort(result2)
Myvlookup = RemoveDupes2(result3)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue lies in your `RemoveDupes2()` function

mainly in that it processes as `keys` both street *names* ("Mainstreet", "Yorkstreet ",...) and *numbers* ("1", "2", ..) *separately* so that after you add "1," the first time (e.g.: from "Mainstreet 1, 2, ...") to the created dictionary, any further occurrence of "1," in `txt` (e.g. "Yorkstreet 1, 2") won't pass the `Not .exists(Trim(x))` check and thus won't be added to the dictionary `keys`

while adopting " " as delimeter is the reason why you get "Yorkstreet 2"

since the first occurrence of "2" is actually a "2," from "Mainstreet 1, 2, " (i.e. it gets "caught" together with the adjacent comma having " " as `Split()` delimeter parameter), while the second is a "pure" "2" from " Yorkstreet 1, 2"

you may want to adopt the following `RemoveDupes2()` code

```
Function RemoveDupes2(txt As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String
    Dim x
    Dim streetsDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim street As String, number As String

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each x In Split(txt, ", ")
            If Trim(x) <> "" Then
                street = Split(Trim(x), " ")(0)
                number = Split(Trim(x), " ")(1)
                If Not .Exists(street) Then
                    .Add street, New Scripting.Dictionary
                    .Item(street).Add number, Nothing
                Else
                    If Not .Item(street).Exists(number) Then .Item(street).Add number, Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then
            For Each x In .Keys
                RemoveDupes2 = RemoveDupes2 & x & " " & Join(.Item(x).Keys, ", ") & ", "
            Next x
            RemoveDupes2 = Left(RemoveDupes2, Len(RemoveDupes2) - 2)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However it gives out an error in the line [Dim streetsDict As New Scripting.Dictionary], stating that this is not defined?

Comment: add to your project the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (Tool->References, scroll the listbox till that library, tick its checkbox and press OK) . and let me know

Comment: Is there maybe a solution without setting this, as I wanted to save this formula as an Excel Add-In and then share it with my colleagu

Comment: Is there maybe a solution without setting this, as I wanted to save this formula as an Excel Add-In and then share it with my colleagues?

Comment: to avoid adding reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime", substitute `.Add street, New Scripting.Dictionary
` with  `.Add street, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`